# Mount a HDD without losing data

Tags: 16.04

I have an old HDD used by an openmediavault NAS in ext4 format. Is it possible to mount this disk to my new Ubuntu 16.04 machine without losing the data on it? Thanks.

Comment: What makes you believe you can lose data by only just mounting?

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned about losing data, then mount it read-only,  e.g. if the device is on /dev/sdb, mount partition 1 using:

```
mount -o ro /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just mount this drive, you shouldn't lose any data at all.

Mounting should never delete any files. You are just telling your filesystem where to show and access this new drive